# how to display screen shot of a webpage as a image in next page

Tags: javascript, php, html

I got the screen shot of the webpage as a image in same page but I want the image to be display in next page not in current page after clicking in confirm button. I tried many options, please suggest me changes required in the below code that I used.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/html2canvas.js"></script>

<script>
    function canvas(){
        html2canvas(document.body, {
            onrendered: function(canvas) {
                document.body.appendChild(canvas);
            },
            width: 1150,
            height:380
        })
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Use an AJAX script on that listens to click on your submit button. What this should do is send the content of the dom element which you appended with the capture picture. Then, on the receiver end (server), use a php script which transforms that code in to a picture. Then, use PHP to load that picture on page 2. You need to take some time on google to learn: 1: AJAX, 2: base64 to jpg in PHP (example)

Comment: This might help you in the right direction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18736023/cannot-send-canvas-data-from-javascript-ajax-to-php-page

Comment: Is the above script is correct for changes to be performed further

Comment: What? That link was just to point you in one direction. How you choose to solve your "problem" is up to you. But he, as I suggested uses AJAX to send the content of the canvas that is created. Then uses a PHP script to save the content it receives to a image file. You can then somehow pass the name of that file back to the browser (visitor) to be displayed on the next page.

Comment: Thanks, for the suggestion, i am trying for it