# Resize images with canvas before uploading

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas

I have recently written a script to upload images. Everything works well. But now I want to resize the image after uploading it. I have done some research on it and I want to try it with the `<canvas>` element. I have parts of the script, others are missing and I don't know how to connect everything.

These are the steps:

1. Upload the image into `img/uploads` - Done.

   `<form action="picupload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <input name="uploadfile" type="file" accept="image/jpeg, image/png">
       <input type="submit" name="btn[upload]">
   </form>`

   picupload.php:

   `$tmp_name = $_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'];
   $uploaded = is_uploaded_file($tmp_name);
   $upload_dir = "img/uploads";
   $savename = "[several code]";`

   `if($uploaded == 1)
   {
   move_uploaded_file (
       $_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'] ,
       "$upload_dir/$savename");
   }`
2. Put the image into a canvas element - Missing
3. Resize it - Part of the code I want to use somehow:

   ```
   var MAX_WIDTH = 400;        
   var MAX_HEIGHT = 300;
   var width = img.width;
   var height = img.height;

   if (width > height) {
       if (width > MAX_WIDTH) {
           height *= MAX_WIDTH / width;
           width = MAX_WIDTH;
       }
   } else {
       if (height > MAX_HEIGHT) {
           width *= MAX_HEIGHT / height;
           height = MAX_HEIGHT;
       }
   }
   ```
4. Replace the existing image with the new resized one. - Missing

It would be very nice if someone would give me some tips to complete it - Thank you!

Comment: Well, how are you uploading your image?

Comment: @Adjit I've added it ;)

Comment: For grabbing the image - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459379/preview-an-image-before-it-is-uploaded; For adding an image to a canvas - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011378/how-to-add-image-to-canvas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(#2-3) Resizing the source image onto a canvas

- Calculate the scaling factor required to fit MAX dimensions without overflow
- Create a new canvas with the scaled dimensions
- Scale the original image and draw it onto the canvas

*Important! Be sure the source image is coming from the same domain as your web page or else `toDataURL` will fail for security reasons.*

(#4) You can convert the canvas from #3 to an image with `resizedImg.src=context.toDataURL`

**Example annotated code and a Demo:**

```js
var MAX_WIDTH = 400;        
var MAX_HEIGHT = 300;

var img=new Image();
img.crossOrigin='anonymous';
img.onload=start;
img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/annotateMe.jpg";
function start(){

    var canvas=fitImageOntoCanvas(img,MAX_WIDTH,MAX_HEIGHT);

    // #4
    // convert the canvas to an img
    var imgResized=new Image();
    imgResized.onload=function(){
        // Use the new imgResized as you desire
        // For this demo, just add resized img to page
        document.body.appendChild(imgResized);
    }
    imgResized.src=canvas.toDataURL();
    
}

// #3
function fitImageOntoCanvas(img,MAX_WIDTH,MAX_HEIGHT){

    // calculate the scaling factor to resize new image to 
    //     fit MAX dimensions without overflow
    var scalingFactor=Math.min((MAX_WIDTH/img.width),(MAX_HEIGHT/img.height))

    // calc the resized img dimensions
    var iw=img.width*scalingFactor;
    var ih=img.height*scalingFactor;

    // create a new canvas
    var c=document.createElement('canvas');
    var ctx=c.getContext('2d');

    // resize the canvas to the new dimensions
    c.width=iw;
    c.height=ih;

    // scale & draw the image onto the canvas
    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,iw,ih);
    
    // return the new canvas with the resized image
    return(c);
}
```

```css
body{ background-color:white; }
img{border:1px solid red;}
```

Comment: thanks a lot! Is there any way to save this new image automatically to the server?

Comment: "Automatically" -- no. But you can use AJAX to upload the resized dataURL (not the imageObject!). Many posts showing "how-to" ... [Here's one of them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18736023/cannot-send-canvas-data-from-javascript-ajax-to-php-page/18747480#18747480). Good luck with your project! :-)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using ajax for upload, since when you upload you redirect to the php page.
But the example I didn't use it either

References:

```
    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12368910/html-display-image-after-selecting-filename

   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459379/preview-an-image-before-it-is-uploaded

    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011378/how-to-add-image-to-canvas 

     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/331052/how-to-resize-html-canvas-element

    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142535/how-to-clear-the-canvas-for-redrawing
```

Here is what I have for html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
    </style>
    <title>Something</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="picupload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="uploadfile" type="file" accept="image/jpeg, image/png">
    <input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>


</script>
</html>
```

For PHP I used a different way for file upload (for instance I store the picture in localhost/):

```
<?php

if(isset($_FILES['uploadfile']['name'])){
    $nameFile=$_FILES['uploadfile']['name'];
    $pathFile = "C:/inetpub/wwwroot/" . $_FILES['uploadfile']['name'];

    $file_tmp2=$_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'];
    move_uploaded_file($file_tmp2, $pathFile);
}


echo ("

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no'>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <style>
    </style>
    <title>Something</title>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id='viewport' ></canvas>
<button onclick='change()'>change</button>
</body>
<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById('viewport'),
context = canvas.getContext('2d');

make_base();

function make_base()
{
  base_image = new Image();
  base_image.src = '").$_FILES['uploadfile']['name'];
  echo("';
    base_image.onload = function(){
    context.drawImage(base_image, 100, 100);
  }
}


function change(){
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    context.drawImage(base_image, 0, 0, 400 ,300);
}
</script>")

?>
```