# HTML Canvas not displaying images

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas

I cannot get my image to display in an HTML canvas using drawImage(). I know the filepath is correct because the image displays just fine when I disable `display: none;`
I know this can occur when you attempt to draw an image before it is loaded, which you can avoid by using the onload property.

Here is the relevant HTML.

```
<canvas id='gameScreen'></canvas>
<img id="imgBall"src="assets/images/ball2.png" alt="ball">
<script type="module"src="src/index.js"></script>
```

Here is the relevant Javascript.

```
// CANVAS SETUP
let canvas = document.getElementById("gameScreen");
canvas.width = 800;
canvas.height = 600;
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

// DISPLAY BALL
let imgBall = document.getElementById('imgBall');

imgBall.onload = function() {
    console.log(imgBall.src + ' successfully loaded');
    ctx.drawImage(imgBall, 10, 10);
}

imgBall.onerror = function() {
    console.log(imgBall.src + ' failed to load');
}
```

What makes this so confusing to me is that I'm not getting any console messages from imgBall.onload, or from imgBall.onerror.

I'm pretty new to Javascript and canvas, so I apologize if the answer is extremely obvious.

Comment: Its possible that the image has finished loading before the javascript has a chance to add the onload handler.

Comment: As an aside, your HTML attributes are missing a space between them. Also, if img is display: none is the browser bothering to load it?

Comment: this code works just fine in a snippet with a random pic, there's something amiss with your image? check the path should it be "./assets/images/ball2.png" or "/assets/images/ball2.png" ?

Answer (score 0):

To fix the issue I am dynamically creating an image tag and then giving it a src AFTER I have added the event handlers for error and onload.

This makes me think that the issue is due to the image loading BEFORE your script tag had a chance to add the event listeners to the img tag.

```js
// CANVAS SETUP
let canvas = document.getElementById("gameScreen");
canvas.width = 800;
canvas.height = 600;
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

// DISPLAY BALL
const imgBall = document.createElement("img");

imgBall.onload = function() {
    console.log(imgBall.src + ' successfully loaded');
    ctx.drawImage(fitImageOntoCanvas(imgBall,25,25), 10, 10);
}

imgBall.onerror = function() {
    console.log(imgBall.src + ' failed to load');
}

imgBall.src = "https://pngimg.com/uploads/football/football_PNG52737.png"


// need to resize because my ball image is huge
// thanks @markE https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38664890/resize-images-with-canvas-before-uploading
function fitImageOntoCanvas(img,MAX_WIDTH,MAX_HEIGHT){

    // calculate the scaling factor to resize new image to 
    //     fit MAX dimensions without overflow
    var scalingFactor=Math.min((MAX_WIDTH/img.width),(MAX_HEIGHT/img.height))

    // calc the resized img dimensions
    var iw=img.width*scalingFactor;
    var ih=img.height*scalingFactor;

    // create a new canvas
    var c=document.createElement('canvas');
    var ctx=c.getContext('2d');

    // resize the canvas to the new dimensions
    c.width=iw;
    c.height=ih;

    // scale & draw the image onto the canvas
    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,iw,ih);
    
    // return the new canvas with the resized image
    return(c);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="gameScreen" height="500" width="500"></canvas>
```

Comment: Who votes against, please explain the reason with at least a couple of words in the commentary. It is very interesting to figure out what exactly is wrong - both to the author of the answer and to everyone else.

Comment: I'm glad I answered this question, ended up using this code almost exactly for placing a logo inside a qr code the very next day.